# Regex: Keep all captures, not just the last repetition

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm having a C# regex problem. The solution is probably very easy, but I just can't get it to work right now.

```
string type = "ARRAY [0..10,0..20,1..2] OF INT";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^ARRAY \[(?:(\d+)\.\.(\d+),?)+\]");
var matches = regex.Matches(type);
```

This code captures only "1" and "2", which is the bounds of the last dimension of the array. I need to capture all dimensions, preferably in the nested format {{0,10},{0,20},{1,2}} but since there will always be two captures for each dimension, the flat format {0,10,0,20,1,2} will do as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have it in the match data, in [`Captures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.aspx):

```
match.Group[1]
     .Captures
     .Cast<Capture>()
     .Select(capture => int.Parse(capture.Value))
     .Zip(match.Group[2]
               .Captures
               .Cast<Capture>()
               .Select(capture => int.Parse(capture.Value)),
         (min, max) => new { min, max })
```

Each group exposes a collection of `Capture`s that will contain all the instances that matched.

`match.Group[1].Captures` contains all of the *min* values, while `match.Group[2].Captures` contains all of the *max* values. The code above simply zips them together to produce the output you need.

Answer (score 2):

`\G` assert position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

```
(?:^ARRAY \[|\G),?(\d+)\.\.(\d+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mI7qF6/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^ARRAY \[([\d]+[.]{2}[\d]+[,]?)+\]")
```

Comment: This captures the three parts "0..10," and "0..20," and "1..2", but I'd rather get the bounds captured separately to ease the int.Parse() part.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure if you can use look-behind in C# but if so, and you only wanted to match the boundaries, something like `(?<=(^ARRAY \[)|([,]))[\d]+[.]{2}[\d]+` should do the trick. This would require a global modifier, again, I'm not that up-to-scratch with C# so I'm not sure if the global modifier is implied by default.

http://regex101.com/r/nB7oM4/1